# Can 'PS' be used as a verb in English?

Tags: usage, abbreviations, verbing

In my native language 'PS' borrrows the meaning of the process when you edit a photo with the help of Photoshop. It could be used as a verb, For example,  'Could you help me to Ps this photo to make it more beautiful?'. I dont know whether 'ps' could be used as a verb in English in this way?

Comment: *Photoshop* is often used as a verb, but I have never seen its abbreviation used as a verb.

Comment: Practically anything can be used as a verb in English.

Comment: I think initialisms are much less likely to be "verbed" than other words.  The only such words that immediately come to my mind are "abecedarian" (someone who is learning the basics of a subject) and "RVing" (using a recreational vehicle to travel a continent's highways).

Comment: P.S.  Postscripts are commonly abbreviated as "P.S."  And there is another very common software package called PostScript.  PostScript is also an Adobe product.  A few common Unix shell commands use "ps" as an abbreviation for "[PostScript](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/P/PostScript.html)-formatted data stream".

Answer (score 1):

You can verbify whatever you want, but people might not know what you mean. However, "photoshop" (note lowercase 'p') as a verb has become fairly popular.

[image]

However, compared to "Photoshop" (mostly as a noun), it is not fairly common.

[image]